# MSSQL Query works on it's own but not as a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have written the following stored procedure

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[OpenOrderReport]    Script Date: 12/05/2021 12:20:35 ******/
SET ansi_nulls ON

go

SET quoted_identifier ON

go

-- =============================================
-- Author:    Bancroft Wines
-- Create date: 12/05/2021
-- Description:  
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Openorderreport]
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @startdate DATETIME = NULL,
  @enddate   DATETIME = NULL
AS
  BEGIN
      SET @startdate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-04-30 23:59:59', 102)
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET nocount ON;

      -- Insert statements for procedure here
      DELETE FROM OPNORD02;
      INSERT INTO [OPNORD02] ( CUSTCODE, ORDERNO, TYPE, [DATE], [VALUE], MARGIN )
      SELECT Customers.cust_acc                       AS CUSTCODE,
             [Sales Order Details].vop_ordn           AS ORDERNO,
             'Invoiced SOP'                           AS TYPE,
             [Sales Order Header].ordidate            AS DATE,
             Round([Sales Order Details].vol_qtty /
                   [Sales Order Details].volcsize
                   *
                         [Sales Order Details].volcprcn /
                   [Sales Order Header].ordexch1, 2)
                                                      AS VALUE,
             Round(Round([Sales Order Details].vol_qtty /
                         [Sales Order Details].volcsize *
                                     [Sales Order Details].volcprcn /
                   [Sales Order Header].ordexch1, 2) -
                   [Sales Order Details].casecost *
                   [Sales Order Details].vol_qtty
                   /
                   [Sales Order Details].volcsize, 2) AS MARGIN
      FROM   vopoline AS [Sales Order Details]
             INNER JOIN voporder AS [Sales Order Header]
                     ON [Sales Order Details].vop_ordn =
                        [Sales Order Header].vop_ordn
             INNER JOIN vslname1 AS Customers
                     ON [Sales Order Header].cust_acc = Customers.cust_acc
                        AND [Sales Order Header].cust_acc = Customers.custaccs
             INNER JOIN vstmain1 AS Products
                     ON [Sales Order Details].prd_code = Products.prd_code
      WHERE  ( [Sales Order Header].ordidate >=
               CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-04-30 23:59:59', 102)
             )
             AND ( [Sales Order Header].ordidate <=
                   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-05-12 23:59:59',
                   102)
                 )
             AND ( [Sales Order Header].ordacode <> 'S' )
             AND ( [Sales Order Header].ord_stat = 5 )
             AND ( Products.grp_code >= '001' )
             AND ( Customers.custanl1 = 'NO' )
              OR ( [Sales Order Header].ordidate >=
                   @startdate
                 )
                 AND ( [Sales Order Header].ordidate <=
                       @enddate
                     )
                 AND ( [Sales Order Header].ordacode = 'S' )
                 AND ( [Sales Order Header].ord_stat = 5 )
                 AND ( Products.grp_code >= '001' )
                 AND ( Customers.custanl1 = 'NO' )
                 AND ( [Sales Order Header].credstyl = 1 )
      ORDER  BY custcode,
                orderno;

    SELECT * FROM OPNORD02;
  END

go
```

However, it doesn't seem to pull any data.

Because of this, i tried to run the query on its own with a written date instead of a parameter.

This worked, but for some reason it will not run in the stored procedure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i'm new to SQL and it would help so much.

Comment: there is no easy way we can help you James without looking at the data , try to run the query  as `select count(*) from ...` to find out which join or where condition is  bringing down the count to 0 and find the root cause

Answer (score 0):

There are some hardcoded dates of `'2021-04-30 23:59:59'` which should be replaced with `@startdate` and `'2021-05-12 23:59:59'` which should be replaced with `@endDate`. If your paramater dates are outside of these hardcoded dates, your desired data may be filtered out.

Also let's remove the line `SET @startdate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-04-30 23:59:59', 102)`

updated stored procedure:

```sql
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[OpenOrderReport]    Script Date: 12/05/2021 12:20:35 ******/
SET ansi_nulls ON

go

SET quoted_identifier ON

go

-- =============================================
-- Author:    Bancroft Wines
-- Create date: 12/05/2021
-- Description:  
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Openorderreport]
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @startdate DATETIME = NULL,
  @enddate   DATETIME = NULL
AS
  BEGIN
      -- SET @startdate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-04-30 23:59:59', 102)
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET nocount ON;

      -- Insert statements for procedure here
      DELETE FROM OPNORD02;
      INSERT INTO [OPNORD02] ( CUSTCODE, ORDERNO, TYPE, [DATE], [VALUE], MARGIN )
      SELECT Customers.cust_acc                       AS CUSTCODE,
             [Sales Order Details].vop_ordn           AS ORDERNO,
             'Invoiced SOP'                           AS TYPE,
             [Sales Order Header].ordidate            AS DATE,
             Round([Sales Order Details].vol_qtty /
                   [Sales Order Details].volcsize
                   *
                         [Sales Order Details].volcprcn /
                   [Sales Order Header].ordexch1, 2)
                                                      AS VALUE,
             Round(Round([Sales Order Details].vol_qtty /
                         [Sales Order Details].volcsize *
                                     [Sales Order Details].volcprcn /
                   [Sales Order Header].ordexch1, 2) -
                   [Sales Order Details].casecost *
                   [Sales Order Details].vol_qtty
                   /
                   [Sales Order Details].volcsize, 2) AS MARGIN
      FROM   vopoline AS [Sales Order Details]
             INNER JOIN voporder AS [Sales Order Header]
                     ON [Sales Order Details].vop_ordn =
                        [Sales Order Header].vop_ordn
             INNER JOIN vslname1 AS Customers
                     ON [Sales Order Header].cust_acc = Customers.cust_acc
                        AND [Sales Order Header].cust_acc = Customers.custaccs
             INNER JOIN vstmain1 AS Products
                     ON [Sales Order Details].prd_code = Products.prd_code
      WHERE  ( [Sales Order Header].ordidate >= @startdate
               -- CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-04-30 23:59:59', 102)
             )
             AND ( [Sales Order Header].ordidate <= @endDate
                 --  CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-05-12 23:59:59',102)
                 )
             AND ( [Sales Order Header].ordacode <> 'S' )
             AND ( [Sales Order Header].ord_stat = 5 )
             AND ( Products.grp_code >= '001' )
             AND ( Customers.custanl1 = 'NO' )
              OR ( [Sales Order Header].ordidate >=
                   @startdate
                 )
                 AND ( [Sales Order Header].ordidate <=
                       @enddate
                     )
                 AND ( [Sales Order Header].ordacode = 'S' )
                 AND ( [Sales Order Header].ord_stat = 5 )
                 AND ( Products.grp_code >= '001' )
                 AND ( Customers.custanl1 = 'NO' )
                 AND ( [Sales Order Header].credstyl = 1 )
      ORDER  BY custcode,
                orderno;

    SELECT * FROM OPNORD02;
  END

go
```

Since no sample datasets were provided and expected results, I cannot assume or suggest otherwise than above what may prevent you from retrieving rows. I would recommend that you check your filters in the where condition (eg. removing/adding them one by one and verifying that the data returned is as expected). You should also do the same for your inner joins as these can filter out records as well .

Comment: This still doesn't seem to pull any rows.

Comment: @JamesTimms Based on the details provided in your question, it is difficult to help you to debug further. I have updated my answer to include a few recommendations that may assist you in this process